# Display WordPress posts in grid using bootstrap not aligned properly

Tags: wordpress, view, grid, posts

Blog Posts with Grid Layout even number columns doesn't display correctly .The problem occurs with 3 column layout also: for each group of 3 posts

```
<div class="main" role="main">
    <div id="content" class="content full">
        <div class="container">
            <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $title = get_the_title();?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_the_ID())) ?><?php 
    the_post_thumbnail('imic_600x400'); ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?><?php } ?>
    <h3><a href=" <?php echo esc_url(get_permalink(get_the_ID())); ?>
                        <?php 
    echo esc_attr($title); ?>
                    </a>
                    </h3>

                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- Pagination -->
                <?php if(function_exists('imic_pagination')) { imic_pagination(); } 
    else { next_posts_link( 'Older Entries');
    previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); } ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
            <?php if(is_active_sidebar($pageSidebar)) { ?>
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar-col">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar($pageSidebar); ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the created HTML structure as follows (in Inspect Element view to verify it works):

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
</div><!--
--><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
</div><!--
--><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
</div>
```

(note the `<!-- -->` HTML comments)

If that solves the problem, try adding the HTML comments into your PHP code.
The reason for this behaviour is the resulting new line being interpreted as a "space" and thus the third item won't fit into the same row because of the added horizontal space.

You could also output the HTML-`<div class="row">...</div>` without line-breaks, eg. by concatenating the markup as one PHP string.